# My washer is saying F51 on maytag bravo quite series 300

Tags: electrical, repair, washing-machine, troubleshooting

I need links diy video to fix it.  I need a manual version also and images

Comment: Please read https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, and then update your question.

Comment: What have you done to try to find this info yourself? Did you use your question title as a search string on your favorite internet search engine? Seems that would have told you exactly what the problem was, then you can use that same search engine to find out how to fix it. I know it's easier to just ask, but it's really not that hard to do the searching yourself. If you _have_ done the searching and can't find an answer, letting us know is a good idea, since most will assume you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick Google search returned this gem in the first result.

> The F51 error may indicate there is a MOTOR ROTOR POSITION SENSOR FAILURE (RPS). The sensor and control board has a connection or fault issue. This error can be cleared by cleaning/reconnecting the sensor OR replacing it. ... Simply disconnecting and reconnecting the sensor plug connection may fix the issue

There's also multiple reports of a centre-bolt on the base of the machine coming loose. If you've recently heard a knocking sound during agitation, this is the most likely cause.

Comment: Just a heads up I have received multiple downvotes for answering posts that violated the site policies and this one is a real winner.

Comment: @EdBeal In which case, there are inconsistencies across stack sites. I spend most of my time on Super User, and a downvoted/poor quality question wouldn't have its answer(s) downvoted AFAIK. That seems pretty toxic.

Comment: Not a poor quality question but one that violates the site policies

Comment: Noted..........